# How to transfer and parse snap graph from python to c++

Tags: c++, python-2.7, graph, swig, networkx

Stanford [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html) is a well-known package for graph mining, and has both Python implementation and C++ implementation.

I have some code in python to do graph mining using SNAP. I also have a C++ function process the snap graph. Now I need to write a wrapper so that this C++ function can be invoked from Python.

The problem is that I don't know **how to parse/dereference the snap graph object from Python to C++**.

The python code looks like: (More explanations come after the code examples)

```
import my_module;
import snap;

G = snap.GenRndGnm(snap.PUNGraph, 100, 1000);

print(type(G));
A = my_module.CppFunction(G);  # customized function
print(A);
```

The CPP wrapper `my_module_in_cpp.cpp` looks like:

```
// module name: my_module, defined in the setup file
// function to be called from python: CppFunction 
#include <Python.h>
//#include "my_file.h" // can be ignored in this minimal working example.
#include "Snap.h"

#include <iostream>

static PyObject *My_moduleError;

  // module_name_function, THE CORE FUNCTION OF THIS QUESTION
static PyObject *my_module_CppFunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  PUNGraph G_py;
  int parseOK = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &G_py);
  if (!parseOK) return NULL;

  std::cout << "N: " << G_py->GetNodes() << ", E: " << G_py->GetEdges() << std::endl;
  fflush(stdout);
  if ((G_py->GetNodes()!=100)||(G_py->GetEdges()!=1000)) {
    PyErr_SetString(My_moduleError, "Graph reference incorrect.");
    return NULL;
  }

  PyObject *PList = PyList_New(0);

  PyList_Append(PList,Py_BuildValue("i",G_py->GetNodes()));
  PyList_Append(PList,Py_BuildValue("i",G_py->GetEdges()));
  return PList;
}

// To register the core function to python
static PyMethodDef CppFunctionMethod[] = {
  {"CppFunction", my_module_CppFunction, METH_VARARGS, "To call CppFunction in C++"},
  {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

extern "C" PyMODINIT_FUNC initmy_module(void) {
  PyObject *m =  Py_InitModule("my_module",CppFunctionMethod);
  if (m==NULL) return;
  My_moduleError = PyErr_NewException("my_module.error", NULL, NULL);
  Py_INCREF(My_moduleError);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "error", My_moduleError);
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu, python-2.7. In case someone may want to re-produce the problem, the `setup.py` file is also provided.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('my_module',\
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/python2.7/','/users/<my_local>/Snap-3.0/','/users/<my_local>/Snap-3.0/snap-core','/users/<my_local>/Snap-3.0/glib-core'],
    library_dirs = ['/users/<my_local>/Snap-3.0/snap-core/'],
    extra_objects = ['/users/<my_local>/Snap-3.0/snap-core/Snap.o'],
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp','-std=c++11'],
    extra_link_args=['-lgomp'],
    sources = ['my_module_in_cpp.cpp'])

setup (name = 'NoPackageName', version = '0.1',\
    description = 'No description.', ext_modules = [module1])
```

Every time I run the python code above, the error message "Graph reference incorrect." is displayed.

Apparently `G_py->GetNodes()` and `G_py->GetEdges()` cause the problem. This must result from `G_py` not pointing to the right address/in right format. I tried using TUNGraph in the cpp code as well, it still does not point to the correct address. **Is there any way that the pointer in C++ can point to the correct address of the original C++ object**?

Although in general it is hard to dereference a PythonObject from C++, but in this case I think it is doable since *Snap-Python is also implemented in C++. We just need to unwrap its python wrapper.* And the snap authors also provided the SWIG [files](https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap-python/blob/master/swig/pungraph.i).

Of course we can write the graph file in the disk, and read from that, but this will result in I/O and incur extra time consumption. And the snap-user-group does not have as much user traffic as stackoverflow.

BTW, there are `networkx` and `stanford-nlp` tags, but no `stanford-snap` or similar tag referring to that tool. Can someone create such a tag?

Comment: Why don't you write your C++ function directly on python? You can achieve the same results with less results. Have a look at scipy, numpy and pandas and that libs may help you

Comment: Do you have a standard _Python_ installation? Or did you build either one of them (_Python_ or _snappy_) from sources? Note that the _snappy_ binary is compiled on _CentOs_ (_RH_ based) while _Ubtu_ is _Debian_ based, so there might be issues coming from here as well. Hm... and for _Lnx_, _snappy_'s _Python_ version seems to be **2.6**

Comment: I must ask the same question.... why can't you do whatever you neeed to do from _Python_? It's not that simple.... accessing object attributes/methods exposed in _Python_ from _C_. You have to follow the internal object representation and for that you need _snappy_ sources (or have to guess which method is which.... for those 2 it wouldn't probably be very hard since they get no arguments, but for others...).

Comment: @alinoz  I'm new to python-C++ hybrid. Many of the existing C++ codes are in `#include "my_file.h"` in the CPP example above. We still need to transfer the graph object to C++ in the end, if we want to use the existing C++ codes.

Comment: @CristiFati I believe I have a standard Python installation. I installed snap.py by the command `python setup.py install --user` from http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html . `pip freeze` returns `snap===4.0.0-dev-redenterprise-x64-py2.7` I have a RedHat machine, and it returns the same result(error).

Comment: @CristiFati The authors provided SWIG files. Does it help?  I have many existing C++ codes. I wish I could do graph mining without re-writing the code.

Comment: Should be useful to have the _.i_ files as well. But either way, I don't know if it is possible to reverse engineer and get the plain _snap_ objects from the _snappy_ wrappers (I think it is possible, but it would require lots of work). Note that your _Python_ code is incorrect, `PUNGraph` (I assume it's part of the _C++_ _snap_ part) is not _Python_ compatible.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for pointing out. The graph generation code in Python is modified from the tutorial (https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/). They use `PNGraph` while I use `PUNGraph`, and it works at my end. It seems that It's not easy to parse the Python snap from C++. One of the authors also hold the same view.